# Android Studio jack compiler - error message to code does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Ever since I tried out Jack compiler in Android Studio to get the lambda support (which I love), I lost the ability to go directly from a compiler error message to code by double clicking on it. Does anyone know, is that a known issue or is there something I need to do, to enable this feature. It is cumbersome to fix compiler errors this way.

Comment: Was fixed in Android Studio 2.3